# Which elements can be nested inside the <dialog> element?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013, dialog

<sub>TL;DR</sub>

**Which elements can be nested inside the `<dialog>` element?**

---

When I look at examples like [this](http://speckyboy.com/2014/09/29/native-dialog-html5-dialog-windows/), [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/a-preview-of-the-new-dialog-element) and [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-dialog-window/) they all place elements like `<h3>`, `<p>` and `<button>` as child nodes to the `<dialog>` element.

However, the Visual Studio (2013) intellisense list only the following elements:

- content
- dd
- dt
- shadow
- template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <dialog role="dialog">
            <content></content>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt></dt>
            <shadow></shadow>
            <template></template>
        </dialog>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, if I add a `<div>` element to the `<dialog>` element

```
<dialog role="dialog">
    <div></div>
</dialog>
```

Visual Studio will complaint that:

> *Element 'div' cannot be nested inside element 'dialog'.
>
>   
>
>   The div element has no special meaning at all. It represents its children. It can be used with the class, lang, and title attributes to mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements.*

I also looked at the [W3 docs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element) but to no avail.

So I ask again: Which elements can be nested inside the `<dialog>` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dialog` element is not part of any approved specification (recommendation). What comes closest to a standard for it is the HTML 5.1 draft, which you cite and which says that any [flow content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#flow-content-1) is allowed. This means pretty much anything you can put inside a document body, surely including `div`. The WHATWG “HTML Living Standard” [description of `dialog`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-dialog-element) has the same content model.

Visual Studio apparently has its own idea of `dialog`.

In any case, [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dialog) (or lack thereof) currently makes `dialog` rather useless except in experimentation and in limited contexts (like application designed to run on a specific browser).

Comment: You're right. I assumed that the `<dialog>` element was part of the html 5 standard. Although this *is* an in-house web app targeting chrome I'll leave that for now as I hate to see all the errors Visual Studio throws at me.

Comment: The `dialog` element was in HTML5 drafts, though flagged as being “at risk”, the dropped in the April 29, 2014, draft due to lack of implementations. It has not been abandoned, it just wasn’t mature enough for “standardization” yet.

Answer (score 3):

Update for 2022+: `<dialog>` indeed made it in our browsers with production-ready support: https://caniuse.com/dialog and as per [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element), [any flow content can be used.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2)

Comment: VS2022 Intellisense Validation (HTML5) appears to be outdated in warning that element 'xxx' cannot be nested within element 'dialog' as the specification now allows it as explained in the link @JanKlan  has provided in this answer.